# React-day-picker show previous month when using numberOfMonths

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using the react-day-picker component and the *numberOfMonths* variable to set the month's display.
The current display shows the current month and next month, but I'm trying to show the *previous* month and the current month.

Current Code

```
<DayPicker
  mode="range"
  selected={selectedRange}
  onSelect={handleRangeSelect}
  numberOfMonths={2}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, you should use `defaultMonth` prop to change the initially displayed month. If you want to control the months yourself you can use the `month` prop instead of `defaultMonth` and use the `onMontChange` even to set it.

[Link to the API reference](https://react-day-picker.js.org/api/types/DayPickerProps)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I change my function and work charm :))

Comment: Glad it worked out :)